# visual studio 2008 suddenly messed up everything?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am creating a website project. But my visual studio 2008 suddenly messed up everything. I don't know what I did. In fact, I didn't change anything. But each page seems messed up. The interface just like be destroyed. It shows everything, but everything is not in a correct position, correct size. Does anyone happened to know how to resolve this? I'm sorry, I really don't know how to discribe what I have faced. It's not a code problem, but it does have something to do with code. Any help is appreciated. OMG! Two pics show as follows. See the second screen shot? All item concentred to the left connor, and become very small. What I found is, all child pages effected by this issue, but for those pages without using masterpage, no effect at all.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you convert it from a previous version, or was the site designed in VS 2008 from the start?

Comment: "It's not a code problem, but it does have something to do with code." is not very descriptive. Are you using source control? What is the diff saying?

Comment: can you give a small example of what it looks like now versus what it's supposed to look like ?

Comment: I use SVN to do source control.

Comment: This project is started using VS 2008,not convert from a previous version.

Comment: Have you tried reverting to a previous version in the SVN? As mentioned above, a screenshot or two would be helpful.

Comment: The probelm is the interface.The items seems all concentrated in a small area, like top left area. Normally, my page is centered, but right now it is left aligned. And the image is not in it's dimention. become very small. In one words, they messed up. But functionally, they works just as fine as they should be. I'm doubting the some project file is destroyed. I tried to revert to previous version, it has no effect.

Comment: Have you tried loading the project on another machine to see if it is an issue with your code or your install/config of VS?

Comment: Tried on a server. Same problem.

Comment: Since you use svn why don't you do a compare between now & your last saved version ? This should give you some idea as to how to fix

Comment: @Johnv2020 Too many files, and I revert the version to this morning, it doesn't work.Have you met this problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very very very unlikely that the exact same corruption has occured just now on your live version of the code and on the last good svn version or that the same error has occurred in Visual Studio at the same time on two separate systems. So there are 3 possible answers as far as I can see

1: You are referencing a file that isn't included in your project or svn, considering the type of error you are seeing try checking what css files you are using

2: The last version in SVN also had this problem, you just didn't go far enough back

3: Something has changed in your environment, has a patch rollout just taken place or have you installed anything new before this error started happening?

Comment: 1. the CSS file is on local machine, each referencing file has a copy on local machin. 2. I think it has nothing to do with those pages. I revert to one month ago, it doesn't work either.3.Even the environment change on local machine, it doesn't run well on a server. BTW, I just found the page which embeded in a masterpage are messed up. For those not in a masterpage, no effect at all. But I revert the masterpage to earlier version, problem still their.

Comment: It happened once several days ago. At that time, I copied files from server, which I backup one earlier. And it resolved the problem. Unfortunately, this time, I forget to do so by update the latest version on server, so it crashed too.

Comment: ok, can you do a diff between the last known good masterpage and the current version, I don't expect to find anything but it just needs to be checked

Comment: Hey man, I just found after delete all content in CSS file, it returns back. I don't know why, but some code in CSS file must cause this problem. The weird thing is SVN does not have a history about CSS file, but it has it. Anyway, I'm back to right track. I will work on the CSS file to check what's going on. Thank you.